# How do I find out how many arguments are being passed

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am writing some C code on Linux.  I want to loop through the *argv[] parameter being passed to main, but I don't know how to stop before getting a seg fault.

```
  i = 0;
  while (i < sizeof(argv)) {
    printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    i ++;
  }
```

This produces a seg fault because sizeof always returns 8.  How do I get the actual number of elements in argv, or apply some kind of test to stop at the end of argv?

Comment: You should read more about *C*, and you absolutely need to learn how to use the `gdb` debugger. Don't forget to compile with `gcc -Wall -g`

Comment: Read also http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/ but first, learn more about C programming (and that `sizeof` some pointer is not related to the runtime size of the memory zone pointed by it).

Comment: Learning C by guessing is dangerous. Get a book.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first argument.. `argc`  should already have the CLI argument count.. Any reason why that isn't used?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if(argc > 1)
 }
```

Comment: I can check that, but I did find that looking for '\0' works.  
     ... while (argv[i] != '\0')....

Comment: Um.. that is a null terminating character to check the end of a string.. so you are just checking the one pointer to a char (the first element of argv really).. not doing what you want

Comment: And on Linux, `argv` is a null-pointer terminated array .... So `argv[argc] == NULL`; I believe it is mandated by Posix.

Comment: And `argc` is **always positive** so `argc > 0` is always true.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Probably because the first argument is a pointer to the program name.. so I have changed it to 1 instead.. but it depends on the argument count I guess. Works for Linux but is it portable code? I didn't know about that.. so thanks anyway :)

Comment: Yes, you are right thanks.. you can edit my answer to add that tidbit. Thanks again.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `argv[argc] == NULL` is required by the C standard.

Comment: @undefinedbehavior: I wrote that in a later commend.

Answer (score 3):

The first argument of main is `argc` which is the number of arguments passed to your program. This is at least 1, which is the name of the executable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  printf("%d\n", argc);
  return 0;
}
```

Invoked as:

```
$ ./a.out 
1
$ ./a.out 1 2 3 4
5
$ ./a.out 1 2 3
4
```

Answer (score 1):

argc contains the count of parameters in argv.